# Is it possible to find out the commit before fast-forward?

Tags: git, git-merge

I did a wrong fast-forwad merge and the master branch points to a commit it should not. Is it possbile to find the commit before I did fast-forwad(so I revert the master branch to that commit) ?

Comment: do you have a remote with a correct master?

Comment: no remote also fast-forward to latest commit

Comment: I'm not sure if that info is kept anywhere in git's internal directory. So unless you used a pull request in github/bitbucket/gitlab to do that merge, I guess you need to try to *remember* where it was before, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `git reflog master` and there should be lines like

```
bbb222 HEAD@{0}: merge xxxx: Fast-forward
aaa111 HEAD@{1}: foo bar baz
```

`bbb222` is the current tip of `master`, and `aaa111` is the one before the fast-forward merge. Restore `master` to `aaa111`

```
git reset aaa111 --hard
```

`git reset --hard` removes all the uncommitted changes. So if you have any changes uncommitted, commit or stash them first.

Comment: Save my day, thanks! BTW, can I use git reset --soft ?

Comment: @Qiulang `--soft` keeps the changes from `aaa111` to `bbb222` in the index and in the working tree. You could choose to keep them if necessary.

Comment: There's also [the `@{}` syntax for mining the reflogs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), with a positive number it goes back that many reflog entries, `master@{1}` is how you tell git to do this lookup for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git reflog` and checkout to that commit you want to!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to check your [packed references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery):

```
$ cat .git/packed-refs
```

And see if your master points there to a previous commit that makes sense to you.